# Reusing a top-level DTO as a child in another DTO

Tags: class-design, json, code-reuse, dto

What is the recommendation regarding re-using DTO's as a child in another DTO?

I'm using ASP.NET Web API (C#) and consuming the results with Angular 1.x (not sure if that really matters).

I have the following DTOs

```
class SiteDto {
 public int SiteId {get;set;}
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
  ...
}

class SiteEventDto {
 // pk
 public int SiteEventId {get; set; }
 // fk
 public int SiteId {get; set;}
 public DateTime EventStartDate {get; set;}
 public DateTime EventEndDate {get; set;}
 ...
}
```

I want to return a list of SiteEvents with a site name (for example). Is there a recommendation for the link between SiteEvent and Site to get this parent information?  For example, I see the following possibilities:

1. **Re-use existing DTO:** Use the existing Site DTO as a property within the SiteEvent DTO (e.g. `public SiteDto ParentSite { get; set; }` )

   - Pros:

     - Code re-use
     - Scalable
   - Cons:

     - Potentially a lot of extra bloat (for web-based/json-based calls especially) due to unneeded properties and possibly additional parent hierarchies
2. **Create new parent DTO:** Create a child-DTO specific to this task (e.g. `class SiteEventSiteDto {` ... ) and reference that through a child property on SiteEventDto

   - Pros:

     - Reduce additional bloat from unused fields
   - Cons:

     - Minimal code re-use
3. **Flatten class structure:** Flatten the class structure to simply include a "SiteName" property in the SiteEventDto (e.g. `public string SiteName { get; set; }` )

   - Pros:

     - Reduce additional bloat (even more)
   - Cons:

     - Minimal code re-use

It probably makes sense to look at each case individually and assess the following questions:

- Do I foresee a need for additional properties off the parent object?
- How difficult is it to add a new property in a flat structure?
- How much bandwidth is the bloat going to really cost the user?

I guess my questions to the community are:

- Is it common practice to re-use a DTO for more than one controller (scenario #1, above) or is that considered a bad practice for some reason? Or, does it make more sense to create a new child DTO or use a flat structure when possible?
- And lastly, do my ramblings above seem like a good approach to this problem?

Comment: Why the downvote? A little constructive criticism might be more helpful than... nothing

Comment: It might be a requirement to comment on a downvote.  My biggest pet peeve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Re-use existing DTO, Create new parent DTO and Flatten class structure

Choosing between reusable code (*sometimes it makes us feel like squaring the circle*) or customization (*sometimes it makes us feel like having a deja vu*) is a matter of needs and preferences.

You already exposed *pros* and *cons* of each solution. Now, you have to balance them:

- Those **pros that suit better your needs**.
- Those **cons that don't prevent you from meeting the requirements**.

#### Assess and answer the following questions:

> Do I foresee a need for additional properties of the parent object?

Providing additional properties (*that might seem unnecessary at first glance*) you could be saving calls to the server. Cutting down concurrency and saving device's resources is always welcome into any system.

> How difficult is it to add a new property in a flat structure?

Depends on how hard is to retrieve the property:

- Do we need to execute additional queries? How many? What kind of queries?
- Do we need to make the actual query more complex? What sort of complexity are we introducing?
- Do we have to call external services?
  ....

> How much bandwidth is the bloat going to really cost the user?

- How often are users going to ask for the complex DTO? *(If it's requested just once during the "session". Is there any cost?)*
- Is it a requirement to make light resources?
- Is important to use the less bandwidth possible?
- Is there any sort of bandwidth consumption limitation?

#### Ok... Too much questions

All these kind of questions might lead to premature optimisation. Start by the simplest one. Apply [KISS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle.

#### Finally...

> And lastly, do my ramblings above seem like a good approach to this
>   problem?

It's necessary to know the project and the requirements, in order to say which solution is advisable/good/best

So far, **all 3 are legit and "good" if they solve the problem.**

Comment: A little late, I had already upvoted, but I marked as answer :)  Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I was approaching this correctly (logically) and I think you confirmed that I was (or we're both equally crazy hah, j/k).

Comment: Never la too late. I hope the answer helped you.